# How to make an iFrame inserted by Chrome Extension draggable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, google-chrome-extension

In my Chrome Extension, I'm trying to add an iFrame containing some clickable buttons on web pages at fixed position. To avoid occlusion, I want to make this iFrame draggable. The reason I need an iFrame is to isolate CSS.

I have tried many hacks such as making a transparent div overlay iFrame, get mouse events and translate jQuery mousemove events to iframe parent div which is jumpy, tried using this library http://javascripttoolbox.com/lib/dragiframe/ but nothing works smoothly.

jQuery UI's draggable() does not work as expected because iFrame interferes with click events.

What should I do?

Comment: Add an element (may look like icon or header) inside the iframe to be used as a grip for moving. Inside the mousemove listener use the event data to change to the iframe position in the parent page.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Like I briefly mentioned, I tried something like that. Here's a video screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cs7jj6sjw2kt3np/test.mov?dl=0 . Problem is it is flaky/ jumpy. I can bet my money it's because iframe is its own window which when repositioned, adjusts the mousemove's x and y coordinates. In this particular case, the handle element that you mentioned is a white `div` and the console logs are (x,y) of iframe. For implementation of make draggable, I referred to http://www.coderholic.com/jquery-draggable-implementation/